# Read mysql column result in awk variable

Tags: awk, grep, mysql, gawk, sql

I am unable to read single VALUE from mysql Query in awk.I am able to read it in bash but not in awk. I want to read the result variable in awk as I want to fire the query only based on some dynamic conditions written in awk.

```
awk '{
 cmd="(mysql --host='abc' --user='def' --password='..' --database='ghf' -sNe \"select VALUE from table where KEY='171-125';\")"
 cmd|getline $lastdiff;
 print "diff is "lastdiff;
}'


diff is

diff is
```

I have tried with `grep -Eo \" [0-9]* \"` also/ It is not helping. I have used both **`system()`** or **`cmd | getline`** to get the result into variable but it is always returning 0.

```
 sudo awk 'BEGIN {
>  myvalue=system("mysql --host='abc' --user='def' --password='..' --database='ghf' -sNe \"select VALUE from table where KEY='171-125';\" ");
>  print "diff is ",myvalue;
> }'
diff is  0
```

Bash is giving the result

```
mysql --host='abc' --user='def' --password='..' --database='ghf' -sNe "select VALUE from table where KEY='171-125';"
1
```

I want to read the numeric VALUE into lastdiff variable in awk. Any recommended solutions.

Comment: `system()` will return the exit status of the command, not the output of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql ... | awk '{ print "diff is", $0 }'
```

Or just

```
mysql ... 'SELECT CONCAT("diff is ", VALUE) FROM ...'
```

From within `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cmd = "mysql ..." }
     { cmd | getline value;
       printf("diff is %s\n", value); # or print "diff is", value;
       close(cmd) }'
```

This will run the command once for each line of input to the `awk` script. Without the `close()`, it would be run once and give `value` the value of each successive output line of the command.

Your script uses `$lastdiff` rather than `lastdiff` with `getline`.  In `awk`, `$lastdiff` refers to field number `lastdiff` of the current input record.

Comment: It is giving the output as 0 while the expected value is 1.Thanks.

Comment: Change the format specifier in `printf()` from `%d` to `%s`. The string read may not be a pure integer?

Comment: with %s empty output just like print "diff is", value. It is printing only "diff is ".It is floating field. Even with %f it is taking 0.000. The expected output should be 1.

Comment: @Aashu I tested the exact code above with `cmd = "ls /"` and it works for me. I get `diff is ` followed by the first name from my root partition. Make sure that `cmd` is set correctly (quoting and such things).

Comment: @Aashu Also, the command should not be in `(...)`.

Comment: It is not working for the mysql query.

Comment: @Aashu The `cmd` string would have to be set something like `cmd="mysql --host=\"abc\" --user=\"def\" --password=\"..\" --database=\"ghf\" -sNe \"select VALUE from table where KEY=\'171-125\'\""`. Or, you could use `awk -v cmd='mysql --host="abc" --user="def" --password=".." --database="ghf" -sNe "select VALUE from table where KEY=\"171-125\"' '{ awk script here }'`. It's always tricky the get quoting within quoting right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64282/discussion-between-aashu-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the variable in bash before passing it to awk with the -v flag and so:

```
cmd=$(mysql --host='abc' --user='def' --password='..' --database='ghf' -sNe \"select VALUE from table where KEY='171-125';\")
awk -v cmd=$cmd '{ some awk script }'
```

Alternatively, if you want to parse the output of mysql, do:

```
awk '{ some awk script }' <<< $cmd
```

Comment: I want to fire the query only based on the certain dynamic condition in awk.Thanks in between.

Comment: You can fire the query from within awk with the system function but getting the returned output back into a variable will be difficult and the system function itself runs the risk of injection.

Comment: @Aashu This was not clear from the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda My bad,I have re-phrased the question.